# Binary Trees in Java: preorderNext, postorderNext, inorderNext

Tags: java, binary-tree

I'm having some trouble with Binary Trees in java. The assignment wants me to build a binary tree and then create functions to return the next node in preorder, postorder, and inorder. So here is my attempt;

```
public class BinaryTree {
    Node root;
    
    private Node addR(Node c, int x) {
        if (c == null) {
            return new Node(x);
        }
        if (x < c.value) {
            c.left = addR(c.left, x);
        }
        else if (x > c.value) {
            c.right = addR(c.right, x);
        }
        else {
            return c;
        }
        return c;
    }
    
    public void add(int x) {
        root = addR(root, x);
    }
    
    public Node preorderNext(Node n) {
        if (n.left != null) {
            System.out.println(n.left.value);
            return n.left;
        }
        else if (n.right != null) {
            System.out.println(n.right.value);
            return n.right;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Empty");
            return null;
        }
    }
    
    public Node postorderNext(Node root, Node n) {
        if (n == root) {
            System.out.println("Empty");
            return null;
        }
        Node parent = n.parent;
        if(parent.right == null || parent.right == n) {
            System.out.println(parent.value);
            return parent;
        }
        Node c = parent.right;
        while (c.left != null) {
            System.out.println(c.left);
            c = c.left;
        }
        System.out.println(c.value);
        return c;
    }
    
    public Node inorderNext(Node root, Node n) {
        if (n.right != null) {
            System.out.println(n.right.value);
            return minValue(n.right);
        }
        Node p = n.parent;
        while (p != null && n == p.right) {
            n=p;
            p=p.parent;
        }
        System.out.println(p.value);
        return p;
    }
    
    Node minValue(Node n) {
        Node c = n;
        while (c.left != null) {
            c = c.left;
        }
        return c;
    }
    
    public Node searchR(Node c, int x) {
        if(c==null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (x==c.value) {
            return c;
        }
        if (x<c.value) {
            c.left = searchR(c.right, x);
        }
        c.right = searchR(c.right, x);
        return c;
    }
}
```

And here is my main;

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BinaryTree test = new BinaryTree();
        test.add(7);
        test.add(5);
        test.add(6);
        test.add(9);
        test.add(3);
        test.add(8);
        test.preorderNext(test.searchR(test.root, 5));
        test.postorderNext(test.root, test.searchR(test.root, 5));
        test.inorderNext(test.root, test.searchR(test.root, 5));
        
    }

}
```

So the code works as far as nothing crashes, but it returns the wrong nodes. I double checked to make sure the searchR method was returning the right value, and it was, but the other functions simply return the wrong numbers. Anyone have any guidance on where I'm going wrong? I'm a little lost since it's not actually an error and clearly an issue within my code. I also can't use collections in this problem, but I don't think that would be relevant here anyway.

Comment: Your `Node` class has a `parent` member, but your `add` method never sets the `parent` member of the newly added node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `searchR` function is screwing up the tree due to the `c.right` and `c.left` assignments. You're very close, though.

After all the `add` calls are complete, your tree looks like this:

```
    7
   /  \
  5    9
 / \  /
3  6 8
```

When you call `searchR(test.root, 5)`, your tree winds up looking like this**:

```
  7
 / \
9   9
```

As you can see, not only is this not a valid binary tree, but many of the nodes are missing, and the node with a value of 9 was duplicated.

Get rid of the assignments, wrap the `.right` traversal in an `else` block, get rid of the final `return` statement, and you'll be good to go:

```
public Node search(Node node, int target) {
    if (node == null) return null;

    if (node.value == target) {
        return node;
    } else if (target < node.value) {
        return search(node.left, target);
    } else {
        return search(node.right, target);
    }
}
```

Your `preorderNext` looks OK.

Your `postorderNext` looks almost OK. The issue is that I don't see you setting up the `.parent` members of the `Node`s, so your `postorderNext` function will always crash with a `NullPointerException` at the `parent.right == null || parent.right == n` conditional check.

Your `inorderNext` will break for the same reason; no `parent` members are set up. My recommendation would be to add a parameter to your `add` function to hold the `parent` node. Then, when you `return new Node(x)`, you can also set the `parent` member appropriately. Note that you should pass `c` as the parent node in each recursive call.

** If you're curious how I figured out the exact nature of the tree after your `searchR` function, I threw a handful of print statements into the `searchR` function and ran it myself. This was the result:

```
Starting recursive call for node 1933863327 and x = 5
5 < 7, doing c.left = searchR(c.right, x)
Starting recursive call for node 146589023 and x = 5
5 < 9, doing c.left = searchR(c.right, x)
c == null, returning null
Recursive call for c.left returned, c.left.value = null
Doing c.right = searchR(c.right, 5)
c == null, returning null
Recursive call for c.right returned, c.right.value = null
Ending recursive call for node 146589023 and x = 5
c.value = 9
Recursive call for c.left returned, c.left.value = 9
Doing c.right = searchR(c.right, 5)
Starting recursive call for node 146589023 and x = 5
5 < 9, doing c.left = searchR(c.right, x)
c == null, returning null
Recursive call for c.left returned, c.left.value = null
Doing c.right = searchR(c.right, 5)
c == null, returning null
Recursive call for c.right returned, c.right.value = null
Ending recursive call for node 146589023 and x = 5
c.value = 9
Recursive call for c.right returned, c.right.value = 9
Ending recursive call for node 1933863327 and x = 5
c.value = 7
```

Comment: Thank you, that is very clear. I just have one follow up question; how do I assign the parent class? Should i do it in the addRecursive or the add function? Should I assign the current node as the parent? Sorry, I'm having a bit of a brain lapse on this one for some reason.

Comment: @DashHarber You should do it in the `addRecursive` function, and you're spot on about assigning the current node as the parent. Your function header might look like this: `public Node addR(Node c, int x, Node parent)` and a recursive call might look like this: `c.left = addR(c.left, x, c)`. You'd want to set the `parent` member in the `if (c == null)` block.

Comment: So I've set that up, but I'm a bit confused still. If I assign something like c.parent = parent, then it gives me a NullPointException. I can't put it after the return statement, obviously, since it becomes in accesbile, but if I put it before, the node doesn't exist yet to assign a parent. Am I misunderstanding?

I also wanted to say a personal thank you. I'm really struggling with this course and have not had the best luck on these sites, but you have been patient and clear and I wanted to express my appreciation for that.

Comment: @DashHarber What I meant was that you should write something to the effect of `Node newNode = new Node(x)`, then do `newNode.parent = parent` and `return newNode`. And you're welcome for the help. As long as you provide enough information about your question, like you've done here, people are generally willing to lend a hand.

Comment: Okay, I think I've figure it out. I set the new node first, then assigned the parent, then returned it. It seems to be working except for the fact that it is printing out the postorder number twice. Looks like I just have an extra print out somewhere. Thank you again for all your help!

Comment: @DashHarber You're welcome! You can click the checkmark outline under my answer to let other SO users know that your question has an answer that worked for you.